# Drawing simple mediation diagram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, diagram

Is there a (preferably easy and straightforward) way to draw simple path diagrams with mediation coefficients in R?

I've been looking to `DiagrammeR` package but that looks like an overkill (and to be honest I failed to figure out how to make a plot).

Other options I know of are [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/) or [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) but those require manual positioning, connecting paths etc.

`mediation` package has a `plot` option but that draws bootstrapped CIs and what I'd like to achieve is a simple path  with coefficients like this one:

[image: source: http://my.ilstu.edu/~jhkahn/medmod.html]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While [@baptiste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46466282/6925293) solution might work as well, I was looking for a publishable format.

Function `plotmat` from `library(diagram)` is the one that got me the closest to my example:

[image: path diagram]

For a reproducible example use:

```
library(diagram)
data <- c(0, "'.47*'", 0,
          0, 0, 0, 
          "'.36*'", "'.33* (.16)'", 0)
M<- matrix (nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE, data=data)
plot<- plotmat (M, pos=c(1,2), 
                name= c( "Math self-efficacy","Math ability", "Interest in the math major"), 
                box.type = "rect", box.size = 0.12, box.prop=0.5,  curve=0)
```

Comment: Cool, but how to make *** more programmable?

Answer (score 7):

Here are two versions of a mediation diagram built with `DiagrammeR` and a third built with TikZ. Each has strengths and weaknesses:

- DiagrammeR + Graphviz:

  - Pros: easy to create diagrams with provided function, lots of options to adjust design of nodes.
  - Cons: few options to adjust text on edges, output is an htmlwidget object that can print to pdf but may require conversion under specific circumstances such as within a for-loop.
- TikZ

  - Pros: highly customizable, including text on edges; easy to generate diagram with provided function
  - Cons: if you need HTML output, it's designed for LaTeX; syntax can be confusing
- DiagrammeR native syntax (offered just for completeness)

  - Pros: code very easy to read, edit for `R` users
  - Cons: even fewer apparent ways to adjust text on edges

I've coded the first and second examples with a function `med_diagram` that uses the `glue` package to assemble the relevant graphviz or TikZ code. The function requires a data.frame that expects one row with columns for relevant labels and coefficients. For the DiagrammeR-specific function, there are also arguments to adjust various elements of the design.

### Diagrammer + Graphviz

```
med_data <-
  data.frame(
    lab_x   = "Math\\nAbility",
    lab_m   = "Math\\nself-efficacy",
    lab_y   = "Interest in the\\nmath major",
    coef_xm = "0.47*",
    coef_my = "0.36*",
    coef_xy = "0.33* (.16)"
  )


med_diagram <- function(data, height = .75, width = 2, graph_label = NA, node_text_size = 12, edge_text_size = 12, color = "black", ranksep = .2, minlen = 3){
  
  require(glue)
  require(DiagrammeR)
  
  data$height  <- height   # node height
  data$width   <- width    # node width
  data$color   <- color    # node + edge border color
  data$ranksep <- ranksep  # separation btwn mediator row and x->y row
  data$minlen  <- minlen   # minimum edge length
  
  data$node_text_size  <- node_text_size
  data$edge_text_size  <- edge_text_size
  
  data$graph_label <- ifelse(is.na(graph_label), "", paste0("label = '", graph_label, "'"))

diagram_out <- glue::glue_data(data,
  "digraph flowchart {
      fontname = Helvetica
      <<graph_label>>
      graph [ranksep = <<ranksep>>]

      # node definitions with substituted label text
      node [fontname = Helvetica, shape = rectangle, fixedsize = TRUE, width = <<width>>, height = <<height>>, fontsize = <<node_text_size>>, color = <<color>>]        
        mm [label = '<<lab_m>>']
        xx [label = '<<lab_x>>']
        yy [label = '<<lab_y>>']

      # edge definitions with the node IDs
      edge [minlen = <<minlen>>, fontname = Helvetica, fontsize = <<edge_text_size>>, color = <<color>>]
        mm -> yy [label = '<<coef_my>>'];
        xx -> mm [label = '<<coef_xm>>'];
        xx -> yy [label = '<<coef_xy>>'];
      
      { rank = same; mm }
      { rank = same; xx; yy }
      
      }

      ", .open = "<<", .close = ">>")  


DiagrammeR::grViz(diagram_out)  
}

med_diagram(med_data)
```

[image: Mediation diagram generated by function]

### TikZ

TikZ and PGF need to be loaded as LaTeX packages in the preamble. The sample code below includes both those packages and some additional commands that, for example, set a global specification for 'mynode' used in the diagram. I received a warning to include `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}` in my preamble but that may not be necessary for others. Note, this code builds on the example provided here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225940/34597

````
---
title: "Sample Rmd"
author: "Your name here"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{tikz}
  - \usepackage{pgfplots}
  - \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
  - \tikzset{mynode/.style={draw,text width=1in,align=center} }
  - \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
---

```{r, load_packages, include = FALSE}
library(glue)
```
  
```{r, load_function}
med_diagram_tikz <- function(data) {
  glue::glue_data(data, 
"
\\begin{figure}
\\begin{center}
\\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\\sffamily]
    \\node[mynode] (m){<<lab_m>>};
    \\node[mynode,below left=of m](x) {<<lab_x>>};
    \\node[mynode,below right=of m](y) {<<lab_y>>};
    \\draw[-latex] (x.north) -- node[auto] {<<coef_xm>>} (m.west);
    \\draw[-latex] (m.east) -- node[auto] {<<coef_my>>} (y.north);
    \\draw[-latex] (x.east) -- node[below=2mm, align=center] {<<coef_xy>>} (y.west);
\\end{tikzpicture}
\\end{center}
\\end{figure}
", 
.open = "<<", .close = ">>"
)
}
```
  
  
```{r create_diagram, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
med_data <-
  data.frame(
    lab_x   = "Math\\\\Ability",
    lab_m   = "Math\\\\self-efficacy",
    lab_y   = "Interest in the\\\\math major",
    coef_xm = ".47*",
    coef_my = ".36*",
    coef_xy = "0.33* (.16)"
  )

tikz_diagram_out <- med_diagram_tikz(med_data)

# requires chunk header to be set to results = 'asis'
cat("\n", tikz_diagram_out, "\n")

```
````

[image: Mediation diagram drawn in TikZ]

### Diagrammer native syntax

This third version of a mediation diagram uses syntax that's more easily understood by `R` users but I don't love how the edge label text gets placed oddly (hence the two alternative versions above).

```
library(DiagrammeR)

# Create a node data frame (ndf)
ndf <- create_node_df(
  n         = 3,
  label     = c( "Math\nself-efficacy","Math\nability", "Interest in\nthe math major"),
  shape     = rep("rectangle", 3),
  style     = "empty",
  fontsize  = 6,
  fixedsize = TRUE,
  height    = .5,
  width     = .75,
  color     = "gray80",
  x         = c(1, 2, 3),
  y         = c(1, 2, 1)
)

# Create an edge data frame (edf)
edf <- create_edge_df(
  from     = c(1, 1, 2),
  to       = c(2, 3, 3),
  label    = c(".47*", ".33* (.16)", ".36*"),
  fontsize = 6,
  minlen   = 1,
  color    = "gray80",
  )

# Create a graph with the ndf and edf
graph <- create_graph(
  nodes_df = ndf,
  edges_df = edf
  )

graph %>%
  render_graph()
```

[image: Example mediation diagram showing edge label text not lining up properly]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the 'psych' package to test your moderation/mediation and it will give you a plot as well.

```
mediate(Output ~ Independent1 + (Mediator), data =mydata)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about ggraph but it's probably a possible route. Here's what 5 minutes of googling lead me to:

```
library(ggraph)
require(igraph)

test <- data.frame(from = c(1,2,3), to=c(2,3,1), coef = letters[1:3])
simple <- graph_from_data_frame(test)
V(simple)$name <- LETTERS[1:3]

ggraph(simple, layout = 'auto') + 
  geom_edge_link(aes(label = coef), 
                 angle_calc = 'along',
                 label_dodge = unit(2.5, 'mm'),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 'mm')), 
                 end_cap = circle(3, 'mm')) + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name),size = 5) +
  theme_graph()
```

[image]

I have no idea how to enforce the geometry (if possible), but the nice thing is that the layout can generalise automatically.

Comment: This could be useful but only with geometry, as you pointed out. Looks like I found an alternative with `diagram` package.