# Plot path diagram with coefficients of mediation models in R

Tags: r

Is there an R package that plots the path diagram (in similar fashion to the figures [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465752/drawing-simple-mediation-diagram-in-r)) of models fitted with the `mediation` package in R automatically?

Comment: try packages `semPlot` and `lavaanPlot`

Comment: They don't work for the mediation package.

Comment: Maybe this post could be helpful (not automatically though): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465752/drawing-simple-mediation-diagram-in-r

Answer (score 0):

The use of `psych` package could help!

```
mediate(Output ~ Independent1 + (Mediator), data =mydata)
```